# What is a word for a person who pretends to work but is really just waiting for others to give them their share when the work is done?

Tags: word-choice, word, word-requests

Similar to moocher and shirker in english, but with their meanings combined and with an element of trying to be sly. Looking for something that would work in a basic sentence, to identify/label a person. For instance, 'he is a ______'

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a specific "word" for that type of a person, but a Chinese idiom (成語) describes such a person well - "好吃懶做, **坐享其成者**", which says a person, who enjoys eating but working, and always sits there waiting to share the fruit (成果) picked by others (through hard work/labor).

Answer (score 1):

- 無 without
- 功 (功勞) credit / contribution
- 受 receive/ accept
- 祿 salary/ reward
- 無功受祿 - get paid/rewards without making any contribution

無功受祿者 - the one who gets paid/rewards without making any contribution

無功受祿之人; **無功受祿的人**

~

- 不 not
- 劳 work
- 而获 but obtain
- 不劳而获 get something without doing anything

~

- 坐 sit
- 享 enjoy
- 其成 the success/ achievements
- 坐享其成 sit idle and  enjoy the fruit of other's labor

**不劳而获, 坐享其成之人**

Answer (score 1):

Probably 偷懒 can meet your requirement. But it often works as a verb. E.g. 他工作中经常偷懒. 他经常偷懒. 他总偷懒.

Answer (score 0):

skiver: 躲避者

malingerer: 装病以逃避职责的人

shirker: 偷懒者

freeloader: 利用别人的慷慨来占便宜的人

她总是怠工的。
She's always slacking.

有的勤奋工作，有的则消极怠工。
There are those who work hard and those who slack.